# Send the [sample-data] for analysis

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [sample-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sample-data) tag is for:

> Sample data is a term used for publicly available sets of data in a variety of formats.

Usually the tag is added to questions which are requesting an set of sample data for data source X. These questions are all off-topic. Other questions using this tag are about problems experienced with a sample data set (like the Northwind database in Microsoft examples). Again, not very useful since it is only a meta-tag.

Shogs check list:

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

   No, the tag does not describe the contents of the question. It merely says something about the source of the data used. It is unambiguous though in my opinion.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   The tag on itself doesn't point to something on-topic. Instead it is usually a marker for off-site resource requests.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No. It is a meta tag.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   It usually refers to sample data sets to be used in databases or other data sources. Questions are about [getting sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39941569/993547) or [generating it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44172520/993547).

Can we get rid of this tag?

Comment: I think I did. It is a unnecessary, off-topic meta-tag @Adriaan (point 2 and 3 from Shogs list)

Comment: Unless people see a bullet point, they believe you are not following Shog guidance.

Comment: @Braiam I tried to take the list and answer the questions.